# Presentations of the dihedral and quaternion groups

Tags: soft-question, finite-groups, quaternions, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

I am reading Lang’s algebra text and he is currently discussion generators of groups and gives the following examples: [image]
Is Lang suggesting here that any two elements of either group which satisfy those relations will generate the group? Or is he instead simply saying that(referring to the dihedral group) the clockwise rotation and reflection about two vertices are generators for the group and that they satisfy those relations(that is, he is alluding to specific generators and stating relations they satisfy)?

Note: I understand that he is using typical notation for the quaternion group but it is easy to see that any pair of quaternions which satisfy those relations will generate the group as well.

Comment: Has Lang stated anywhere that he is specifically using the symbol $\sigma$ to stand for clockwise rotation (through $\pi/2$, presumably), and $\tau$ for reflection around a diagonal? If not, then he is saying the group is generated by any two elements satisfying those two relations. Similarly for the quaternions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson He did not. I was unsure because these generators are used in Dummit and Foote. Thank you!

Comment: Well, $\sigma^4=1$ means $\sigma$ must be one of the two $\pi/2$ rotations, and $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma^3$ means $\tau$ must be one of the "flips", but whichever choice you make, you get the same group.

Comment: Please try to avoid images; they are not searchable, and screen readers cannot handle them (this one, in particular, is quite blurry). The site supports excellent mathematical typesetting, so you should be able to put all the content in without an image.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right, so just to be clear, Lang is asserting that two non-identity elements which satisfy those relations generate the group, correct? I should’ve made that distinction before.

Comment: Yes. And see also the answer Declan has posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Gerry Myerson's comments, I would like to offer another perspective: what I personally would understand by reading this is that Lang is defining a *presentation* of a group and defining it to be $D_8$ or $Q_8$.

What I mean by this that, in the case of the dihedral group, we ignore any visualizations with the square - just take a generating set $\{\sigma, \tau\}$ and form the group $\langle \sigma,\tau\mid \sigma^4=e,\tau^2=e,\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma^3\rangle$, which is a definition of some group, which we call "the group of symmetries of the square", or $D_8$. The same applies for the quaternions.

Conversely, once we define $D_8,Q_8$ like this, we cannot take any old elements $\sigma',\tau'\in D_8$ that satisfy the relations and claim that they generate the group - what if $\sigma'=\tau'=e$? We would need to additionally require that $\sigma',\tau'$ generate a group of order 8.

Comment: I had briefly thought of this perspective. So when he says $\sigma^4=1$ does he mean that $\sigma$ is strictly of order 4(so that, as you said, we cannot take any old elements that satisfy the relations)?

Comment: Yes, from my point of view he is saying that “all we know” about $\sigma$ is that $\sigma^4=1$. So if some element $\sigma’$ happened to have order 2, we would still have that relation, but it would not necessarily generate the same group. Note that in general, saying $x^4=1$ in an arbitrary presentation does not necessarily mean $x$ is of order 4: the other relators could allow a deduction $x^2=1$, for example.

Comment: So he is(or could be) essentially asserting that two elements which generate the group must satisfy those relations and not that two elements which satisfy those relations are generators? I understand that this isn’t necessarily what is meant by the presentation interpretation, but that seems to be a similar alternative perspective.

Answer (score 2):

It might be well to recall the way that presentations of groups work.  The presentation  $\langle S|R\rangle $ refers to the group which is the quotient of the free group on the generators, the elements of  $S $, by the normal subgroup,  or the so-called normal closure, of the subgroup generated by the relations $R $.